# Rerunning the same command with a different parameter

Tags: shell, command-line, scripting

I know that I can run the following command

```
ls Some{File,Folder}
```

And it is equivalent to running this:

```
ls SomeFile SomeFolder
```

(I also use it a lot for things like `mv place_{a,b}`)

However, I was wondering if there was a different shortcut where I could do something like this:

```
run-command --a --whole --lot --of --flags parameter a; \
     run-command --a --whole --lot --of --flags parameter b
```

And I only had to type `run-command --a --whole --lot --of --flags parameter {a,b}` or something similar.

Comment: That depends on `run-command`, many Unix commands handle several file arguments in sequence.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming that you are using the GNU `bash` or something similar:

Perhaps a `for` loop?

```
for x in a b
do
    run-command --a --whole --lot --of --flags parameter $x
done
```

which can also be written in one line as  `for x in a b; do run-command --a --whole --lot --of --flags parameter $x ; done`

Comment: or if you have a lot you want to run you can use bash expansion like so `for x in {a..z}; do ; run-command --a --whole --lot --of --flags parameter $x ; done`

Comment: What goes there can be a space separated list generated in *many* ways. So yeah, `{a..z}`, `*.pdf`, `$(find ...)`...

Comment: I don't know why my mind didn't jump to loops.  Thanks!  This will probably be what I use.  The function idea is good, but I like this better.

Comment: The one-liner only worked for me after removing the `;` following the `do` keyword.

Comment: @jimp Thanks, I've changed the code to remove that `;`.

Answer (score 11):

If you aren't scripting this and just want to run it easily on a command line, the `xargs` command is probably what you are looking for.

xargs will take a bunch of content from the standard input, and use it as arguments for a command, running that command multiple times if needed.

Try the following:

```
echo -n parameter a,parameter b | xargs -n 1 -d , run-command --a --whole --lot --of --flags
```

Echo's `-n` flag avoids printing a trailing new line character (caused issues with some commands while passing parameters through).

In this example, you are simply giving xargs the permutations you want it to run.

The `-n 1` flag to tell xargs to use just 1 of the arguments per run.

The `-d ,` flag tells xargs to look for a "," on the input as the deliminator between arguments to run.  (Note that if the argument has a "," in it you will need to change this to something else.  If your arguments have no spaces in them you can omit this flag altogether.)

See `man xargs` for more info.

Comment: echo needs `-n` in order to avoid adding a new line character. causes issues with some commands while passing parameters with xargs

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a function, which doesn't limit you to having your changing argument at the end:

```
runcom() { run-command --a --whole --lot --of --flags parameter "$1" ; }

runcom a
runcom b
```

Answer (score 4):

You can perform substitutions in the previous command. This won't work with your {a, b} example, because all instances of 'a' will be replaced with a 'b'. But imagine you want to execute the following commands:

```
run-command --a --whole --lot --of --parameter --format xml
run-command --a --whole --lot --of --parameter --format son
```

You can do it with

```
run-command --a --whole --lot --of --parameter --format xml
!!:s/xml/json/
```

Bash will do the substitution and run

```
run-command --a --whole --lot --of --parameter --format json
```

Use gs (global substitution) to perform several substitution, not only one.

Answer (score 2):

There is `alias` command in bash:

```
$ alias shotcommand='run-command --a --whole --lot --of --flags parameter'
```

The usage is: `$ shotcommand a`

Comment: There are also functions, if the code is a bit more complex :-)

Comment: This solution only works if my changing parameter happens to be the last one, correct?

Comment: Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

`xargs` combined with your original suggestion of curly braces is handy here:

`echo Ahoy{1,2,3}|xargs -n1 echo`

Or with your example:

`echo {a,b} | xargs -d' ' -I% echo run-command --a --whole --lot --of --flags parameter %`

With the added %, you can place your parameter anywhere you want in the command.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note however that this looks like a minor variation of the [answer by @hobadee](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/255165/377345). If that was not the intention, please edit your post to make the difference in the approach more prominent. Otherwise, it should probably be an edit suggestion to that answer instead.