Using bash history expansion, how do I rerun the last command with a different last word?
NOTE: I plan on answering my own question.
This is the last command I ran on the command line:
git co head -- a/path/to/a/file.ts

I want to run this a few more times but with different file paths for the last argument/parameter. This page explains history expansion, and I think the answer I'm looking for is in this subsection, but it lacks examples.
Using history expansion, how would I rerun the previous command with a different file path? For example, how would I run:
git co head -- a/path/to/another/different-file.ts


This is probably a duplicate but I haven't been able to find the answer I'm looking for. These posts look like they might have the answer but they didn't:

Rerunning the same command with a different parameter
Replace the last word of last command but keep the first


Assuming the last command was git co head -- a/path/to/a/file.ts here's how to use history expansion to run git co head -- a/path/to/another/different-file.ts:
    !:0- a/path/to/another/different-file.ts
The word designators documentation provides the pieces of the puzzle, but it's on you to put them together. Here's a breakdown of each history expansion symbol:

!: Refer to the previous command

:: The next symbols will refer to word designators (of the previous command).

0: Refer to the first word (git)

-: Refer to a range after the first word. If the next symbol were another number, this would expand to that range of words (from the previous command). But, if the last symbol is a -, the next number defaults to the second to last word.
For example, if the expanded command had 5 words, 0- refers to the first 4.


There is actually a shorter way to write this. You can omit the 0: !:- is equivalent to the above, because when the 3rd parameter is omitted, it defaults to 0.
NOTE: I have bind Space:magic-space enabled, so the space key expanded !:0- to git co head -- in my terminal. I don't think this should have any effect on the answer, but let me know if I'm mistaken.

You should just be posting this as an answer to https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/60781/70524

@muru I wouldn't know how to use history expansion to do this on a single line like that question is asking

That's fine, they says "or something similar", so this is good enough. Also https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/163812/70524 is well received and takes a similar approach
